# Which version of SQL Server comes with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a confusion about the version of SQL Server which is shipped with Visual Studio 2010 ?

Is it SQL Server 2005 or 2008 or something else ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version is SQL Server 2008 Express.

I can't find any documentation that directly mentions this, but the [product comparison page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison) mentions SQL Server 2008 under "Software for Development and Testing" with a note that one requires a license. The installer comes with the express edition which is free.

Answer (score 1):

it is Sql Server express edition

*"The Visual Studio 2010 installer gives you the option of installing SQL Server 2008 Express Edition"*

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 comes with SQL Server Express 2008 (not 2008R2).

Answer (score 1):

SqlServer 2008 Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 comes with SQL 2008 express edition.